# could someone help me to understad this code logic , how it works?

Tags: javascript

```js
var eatsPlants = true;
var eatsAnimals = false;
var category = eatsPlants ? (eatsAnimals ? "omnivore" : "herbivore") : (eatsAnimals ? "carnivore" : "undefined");
    
console.log(category);
```

//i don;t understand that code it how it check multiple things

Comment: [conditional operator (? :) documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: To avoid being downvoted, you could read How to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 7):

```js
var category = eatsPlants ? (eatsAnimals ? "omnivore" : "herbivore") : (eatsAnimals ? "carnivore" : "undefined");
```

Well, that is the same as

```
if(eatsPlants)
  if(eatsAnimals) category = "omnivore";
  else category = "herbivore";
else 
  if(eatsAnimals) category = "carnivore";
  else category = "undefined";
```

The structure of that conditional operator is as follows:

```js
(condition) ? (outcome if condition is true) : (outcome if condition is false)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just like an if statement, but made simplier.
First goes a condition (`eatsPlants`, returns true if it's true), later if it's true (`?`)goes to the second statement,the first parenthesis, which evaluates if `eatsAnimals` is true, and returns *omnivore* or *herbivore* depending on its value. If the first statement (eatsPlants) was false (`:`), goes to the second parenthesis, `eatsAnimals`. If it's true category will be *carnivore*, else *undefined*.
In this case, it would return *herbivore*, as `eatsPlants` is true and `eatsAnimals`, false.

With `if` statement it would be sth like this

```js
var eatsPlants = true;
var eatsAnimals = false;
var category;
    if (eatsPlants)    
      if(eatsAnimals)
        category="omnivore"
      else
        category="herbivore"
    else
      if(eatsAnimals)
        category="carnivore"
      else
        category="undefined"
```

Answer (score 1):

(x?y:z) This is ternary operator. If x is evaluated to be true, the expression will return y, else z.
So, in your example:

```
var eatsPlants = true;
var eatsAnimals = false;
var category = eatsPlants ? (eatsAnimals ? "omnivore" : "herbivore") : (eatsAnimals ? "carnivore" : "undefined");
```

`(eatsAnimals ? "omnivore" : "herbivore")` will result to "herbivore" since eatsAnimals is false.
and `(eatsAnimals ? "carnivore" : "undefined")` to "undefined".

so `category = eatsPlants? "herbivore": "undefined"` will result to "herbivore" as eatsPlants is true